# Add custom php logic file to Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, routes

I'm looking for a simple solution to add a custom php file and route to a Wordpress website.

Let's say I have a page with a simple form. I want submit that form through ajax and handle the form submission myself in a custom php file. Basically I just want to create a simple route where I can put all the logic and output a json in return.

Wordpress is kinda new to me, I was wondering, what's the best way to achieve that ?

**edit:**

I would like to add an url like http://mywebsi.te/validate that redirect to validate.php and output a json file from there.

Comment: not clear what you're asking...

Comment: WordPress is not like a MVC framework, so the routing algorithm doesn't really work with it. Each implementation can be done in multiple ways. Respecting your requirement (a form and ajax handler), you could look into two thing, `shortcode` to produce the form and wp_ajax to handle ajax request and send response. Try gogling, and you will get tons of solutions. [Here](http://w4dev.com/wp/wp_ajax/) i tried to explain how to use ajax in WP

Comment: @Jakub: sorry, I edited my post. I hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :--

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Hope this will help you...